# how to use variable label instead of variable name in r plots?

Tags: r, hmisc

My dataframe (df) with column names "8A_1" and 8A_2" is:

```
   8A_1 8A_2
1     2    2
2     4    3
3     4    4
4     4    3
5     4    3
6     1    4
7     2    4
8     2    4
9     4    3
10    4    4
```

The variable labels are (which are added to the variables with the help of the Hmisc package)

```
var.labels = 
    c("8A_1"="Variable 1", 
      "8A_2" = "Variable 2")



library(Hmisc)
  label(df) = lapply(names(var.labels), 
                     function(x) label(df[,x]) = var.labels[x])
```

> `var.labels`
>                       8A_1                 8A_2 
>                  "Variable 1"         "Variable 2"
>
> `plot (df$"8A_1", df$"8A_2")`

The above command marks df$"8A_1" and df$"8A_2" in the axes. It does not the variable labels that I want. How can I get variable labels instead of variable names in plots or in other statistical analysis (as it is done for example in SPSS)?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this

```
plot (df$"8A_1", df$"8A_2", xlab=label(df)[1], ylab=label(df)[2])
```

If you want to change the variable names in lm, try this

```
var.labels = 
  c("8A_1"="Variable_1", 
    "8A_2" = "Variable_2")
names(df) <- var.labels[names(df)]
lm(as.formula(paste(make.names(var.labels), collapse="~")), data=df)
```

Comment: thanks, this plot command is working fine. However, in other commands the result is not as expected. For example. the following gives the result,

Comment: lm (df$"8A_1" ~ df$"8A_2", xlab=label(df)[1], ylab=label(df)[2])

Call:
lm(formula = df$"8A_1" ~ df$"8A_2", xlab = label(df)[1], ylab = label(df)[2])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   df$"8A_2"  
     1.5174       0.4998  

Warning message:
In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
  extra arguments c("‘xlab’", "‘ylab’") are disregarded.
>

Comment: you can't use xlab, ylab arguments in lm